# EF Core 1.0 with ASP.NET Core 1.0 MVC WebApi error 404

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, iis-7.5, entity-framework-core

I have a small application that uses EF Core 1.0 with ASP.NET Core 1.0 MVC WebApi, is working perfectly in kestrel self-hosting scenarios (IIS Express) .When i publish on IIS 7.0, i get 404 error when i call method use EF Core, but when i call method that does not use EF Core it work perfectly.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyModelController : Controller
{
    private readonly IExampleRepository _exampleRepository;

    public MyModelController(IExampleRepository exampleRepository)
    {
        _exampleRepository = exampleRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet("GetTestAll")] //RUN PERFECTLY ON IIS
    public IEnumerable<string> GetTest()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4" };
    }

    // GET: api/mymodel
    [HttpGet("", Name = "GetAll")] //ERROR 404 ON IIS
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(_exampleRepository.GetAll().Select(x => Mapper.Map<MyModelViewModel>(x)));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //logg exception or do anything with it
            return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
```

...

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var configurationSection = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<DataBaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configurationSection.Value));
        // Add framework services.

        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddScoped<IExampleRepository, ExampleRepository>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<MyModel, MyModelViewModel>().ReverseMap();
        });

        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

**Extract project.json**

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",

"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"AutoMapper": "5.0.0"
```

}
}

What is the configuration for using EF Core 1.0 with ASP.NET Core 1.0 MVC WebApi on IIS Server.

Thanks for your help. You would find at this url an application answering the same criterion that will give a 404 error after being pulse on IIS 7.0

https://github.com/FabianGosebrink/ASPNET-Core-Entity-Framework-Core

Comment: How do you call it? `GET example.com/api/mymodel`?

Comment: On IIS i use Postman with this url : http://localhost:8088/api/mymodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when I use a connection string with secure integer and deploy it on an IIS 7 on my workstation
IIS uses the name of my computer and not mine as the identifier for Entityframework core.

Answer (score 0):

> is working perfectly in kestrel self-hosting scenarios (IIS Express) .When i publish on IIS 7.0, i get 404 error

It looks like an issue related to your publish process, not to EF because it's working when you debug.

Either your `_exampleRepository.GetAll()` or `Automapper` probably need a file that is missing in your published project.

In your `project.json` file you should include a list of everything you want to be copied during your `publish` process. For example mine looks like this

```cs
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config",
      "appsettings.Development.json",
      "appsettings.Production.json",
      "Views",
      "Resources/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I do not see what the missing files are below the publishOption part of project.json :  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "appsettings.Production.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

Comment: You should activate the detailed error feature to get it even when running a published version of your website [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting). Instead of a 404 you would know what's going on. I believe your HTTP request hits your controller's method but the 404 happens inside

Comment: Instead of hosting it on IIS you can also try to publish into a folder and run it locally on your machine. `dotnet publish ./src/YourProject --runtime win-x64 --configuration Release` then go to `./src/YourProject/bin/Release/netcoreapp1.0/publish/` and run `dotnet YourProject.dll`

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to use routing is to define the route in a separate route attribute.

So, your code should look like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyModelController : Controller
{
    private readonly IExampleRepository _exampleRepository;

    public MyModelController(IExampleRepository exampleRepository)
    {
        _exampleRepository = exampleRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet] //RUN PERFECTLY ON IIS
    [Route("GetTestAll")]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetTest()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4" };
    }

    // GET: api/mymodel
    [HttpGet] //ERROR 404 ON IIS
    [Route("GetAll")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
             return Ok(_exampleRepository.GetAll().Select(x =>   Mapper.Map<MyModelViewModel>(x)));
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //log exception or do anything with it
            return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
}
```

Give it a try.